# Google app engine own domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

Im having trouble with Google App Engine and using my own domain. I have a domain that i'm also using in Google Apps for Work.
I have connected my GAE project in Google Apps so they are linked.
I have added my custom domain in GAE, verified ownership and it seems to be correct.

Here is a picture of the GAE settings.
[image]

And on Google Apps for work.
[image]

The other setting I know I have to do is on my domain registrar. I have added the records from GAE, from the picture I uploaded.
Im using one.com as a domain registrar and my DNS settings look like this:

[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong that you can see directly like "Hey what's this guy doing lol" or does it seem correct at first sight?

Thankful for any help in the right direction.

#

EDIT:
After following the tip from comment, I have verified and mapped the domain "lkpgpremiumcars.com". And added "beta" as subdomain. My "Custom domains" looks the same (like below):
[image]

I also removed A and AAAA-records and added a CNAME.

Waiting for DNS update to see if it works.

## EDIT 2:

Still dont work.
BTW is it normal behavior that if I select the same subdomain again it says this:
[image]

Or is is just because it already points to this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add this as a sub-domain.

- First remove the custom domain (beta.lkpgpremiumcars.com) from the developers console.
- Remove the A and AAAA records that you've added to the DNS.
- Follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application) and on step 1, only add the domain 'lkpgpremiumcars.com' and verify. This doesn't mean you're pointing the naked domain to your application.
- Once it's verified, refresh the page and now you should have the domain available on step 2.
- Select the second option on step 2, put 'beta' on the text box and select the previously added domain from the drop down beside. Click Add.
- Go back to your DNS settings and add a CNAME record for 'beta' pointing to 'ghs.googlehosted.com.
- Allow some time for propagation and it should work!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and get back tomorrow if it works or not.

Comment: I still doesn't work. Do you have any idea of what it can be?

Comment: I'm seeing auto redirection to HTTPS for beta.lkpgpremiumcars.com.Have you uploaded SSL certificate? If you do no wish to redirect to HTTPS automatically, are you enforcing SSL on your app engine configuration?

Comment: Im forcing ssl yes. Somehow thought that it could cause a problem, but wasent sure. Im running with certificates in golang that I think works. But I havent uploaded them to GAE. I get some errors, but will check on that.

Comment: OMG, it works! I had problems uploaded cert before, but now It works and I can access my page! Thanks sooo much for taking time to help me! You're a good person!